# ImportError: libavcodec.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I was installed opencv with pacman,
when i try to import opencv, i have this error:

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libavcodec.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

how can I fix this error?

**EDIT**

```
sudo pacman -Ss libav
extra/gst-libav 1.4.4-1 [installed: 1.4.1-1]
    Gstreamer libav Plugin
extra/libavc1394 0.5.4-2 [installed]
    A library to control A/V devices using the 1394ta AV/C commands.
community/ffms2 2.20-2 [installed]
    A libav/ffmpeg based source library and Avisynth plugin for easy frame
    accurate access
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you don't have the correct libraries installed. Try a search using `pacman -Ss libav`.

On OpenSuSE this is part of `libavcodec52` which says that it is related to `ffmpeg`. Check if you have `ffmpeg` installed at well as dependencies *should* pull in libavcodec.

**EDIT**

After reading the arch [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FFmpeg), it looks like `ffmpeg` does provide the `libavcodec` requirement.

Comment: @SailorCiro see my edit

Comment: @28 So it doesn't look like it is installed, unless it is in `ffms2`. Hmm...What is the output of `ldconfig -v | grep libavcodec.so`?

Comment: ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib64' given more than once
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/libx32: No such file or directory
 libavcodec.so.55 -> libavcodec.so.55.69.100

Comment: @28 So, you have `libavcodec` version 55 and you need `libavcodec` version 56.

Comment: how i can update it? or install 56 v?

Comment: @28 best answer is to wait until someone updates the package; however, you could download and compile by yourself. I don't recommend it. I recommend asking one of the [maintainers](http://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/ffmpeg) about this

Answer (score 1):

Same issues faced on centOS when checking the ffmpeg packages are installed and version :

```
 #/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg

/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavdevice.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

or

```
# ldd `which ffmpeg`
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb32d8000)
    libavdevice.so.56 => not found
    libavfilter.so.5 => not found
    libavformat.so.56 => not found
    libavcodec.so.56 => not found
    libpostproc.so.53 => not found
    libswresample.so.1 => not found
    libswscale.so.3 => not found
    libavutil.so.54 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f75f2ef8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f75f2c74000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f75f28df000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f75f3126000)
```

Solution:

Now, check the library path, open ld.so.conf

```
# vim /etc/ld.so.conf

include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/local/lib
/usr/lib
```

Finally save and quit **:wq!**

Now, check with same command,

```
# ffmpeg -v
ffmpeg version N-73873-gcee7acf-syslin Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
  configuration: --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --extra-libs=-lx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslin --enable-libass --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl
  libavutil      54. 28.100 / 54. 28.100
  libavcodec     56. 50.101 / 56. 50.101
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 25.100 /  5. 25.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```